# How to enable hotkey highlighting in IntelliJ IDEA on macOS?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

Like this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OU6SA.png)

I don't know how to turn it on, so I only surfed the Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is provided by [Presentation Assistant](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7345-presentation-assistant) plugin. You can install it from the marketplace [according to JetBrains documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html), and restart the IDE.